# change permission for files only

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have multiple directories that contain multiple files that require executable permission. I tried with the following yaml, it does change all the files permission to 744, but it also changed the folder `files` and `bin` to 744. Any way to do it so it will make changes to the files only, but not directory?

```
- name: chmod
  ignore_errors: yes
  file: 
    path: '{{ item.path }}'
    state: '{{ item.state }}'
    owner: '{{ item.owner }}' 
    group: '{{ item.group }}'
    recurse: '{{ item.recurse }}'
    mode: '{{ item.mode }}'
  with_items:
    - { path: '/opt/files', state: directory, owner: dummy, group: dummy, recurse: true, mode: 744 }
    - { path: '/opt/bin', state: directory, owner: dummy, group: dummy, recurse: true, mode: 744 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like below. Haven’t executed the code though so bit of tweaking may require.

```
- name: Find files
  find:
    paths:
      - /opt/files
      - /opt/bin
    recurse: yes
  register: file_list

- name: chmod
  ignore_errors: yes
  file: 
    path: '{{ item.path }}'
    owner: 'dummy' 
    group: 'dummy'
    mode: '744'
  with_items:
    - “{{ file_list.files }}”
```